# Android error on version 5.1.0

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop, fresco

I am getting this error,
App is working on other versions and not on only 5.1.0.
I am using fresco android image library here. I have support library in place also the setting as correct in setting support library is selected.

```
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992): Process: com.s5.selfiemonkey1, PID: 21992
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/Pools$SynchronizedPool;
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.ArtBitmapFactory.<init>(ArtBitmapFactory.java:61)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.buildPlatformBitmapFactory(ImagePipelineFactory.java:251)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.getPlatformBitmapFactory(ImagePipelineFactory.java:261)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.getAnimatedImageFactory(ImagePipelineFactory.java:145)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.getImageDecoder(ImagePipelineFactory.java:199)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.getProducerFactory(ImagePipelineFactory.java:269)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.getProducerSequenceFactory(ImagePipelineFactory.java:291)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.getImagePipeline(ImagePipelineFactory.java:229)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier.<init>(PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier.java:46)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier.<init>(PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier.java:38)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier.<init>(PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier.java:32)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco.initializeDrawee(Fresco.java:43)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco.initialize(Fresco.java:39)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.s5.selfiemonkey1.MyApplication.onCreate(SelfieMonkeyApplication.java:109)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4638)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.Pools$SynchronizedPool" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.s5.selfiemonkey1-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.s5.selfiemonkey1-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    ... 25 more
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.Pools$SynchronizedPool
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):        ... 26 more
09-03 11:01:48.564: E/AndroidRuntime(21992):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: some code will be helpful

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError you need to check if you have referenced the library properly

Comment: did you add your activity class to Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I sorted out the issue. It was not with the code but the android-v4 jar version mismatch in my app and one I imported as library. I replaced one and it worked